# Добавить ответ по умолчанию в подтверждении скрипта

Tags: bash, shell, скрипт

Есть конструкция:

```
read -p "Are you sure? "
```

Есть возможность добавить ответ по умолчанию, что бы по итогу выглядело это так:

> Are you sure? y

В таком случае пользователю останется только нажать ввод

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
read -e -n1 -p "Вы уверены? [Y/n] " x
if [[ $x =~ ^$|[Yy] ]]
  then echo "Вы согласны"
  else echo "Вы не согласны"
fi
```

для срабатывания положительного ответа у нас в **regexp** прописаны ( =~ ^$|[Yy] ) два условия:

1. ответ по умолчанию, то есть тогда когда нажимается только **Enter**
   что соответствует пустой строке - "**^$**"
2. введён один из символов - **Y** или **y**

при любых других условиях будет отрицательный ответ.